# Questions about the Fabry Gap theorem and the convergence of power series.

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

The [Fabry gap theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabry_gap_theorem) says that if $ f(z)= \sum_n \alpha_n z^{p_n}$ has radius of convergence $1$, where $p_n$ is an increasing sequence of integers with $p_n/n \to \infty$, then the unit circle is a natural boundary for this series.
Polya however proved that if $p_n/n \to \ k $ for  some real $k$ then there exists a sequence $\alpha_n$ whose circle of convergence is the unit circle and for which the unit circle is not the natural boundary.

But that brings a question to me, what if $\alpha_n$ has the elements where n is a power of 2 removed but not anything else. Then obviously $p_n/n \to \ 1$ so it should be well defined for any z, and yet it doesn't make sense to me that you can have two functions that do not have the unit circle as a natural boundary, and yet the fucntion that is the difference between the two does have the unit circle as a natural boundary.

Can someone explain what I'm not getting?

Comment: not sure that I understand which are the two series in cause; if one chooses $p_n$ to be the natural numbers minus the powers of two and $\alpha_n$ per Polya to make $\sum \alpha_n z^{p_n}$ of radius $1$ and with analytic continuation at some point on the unit circle, what is the other series of this type (radius $1$ and analytic continuation at some unit circle point) st the difference has unit circle as natural boundary?

Answer (score 3):

The converse theorem starts from a sequence $p_n$ such that $p_n/n \to k$ and guarantees the existence of a sequence $\alpha_n$ such that the radius of convergence of $ f(z)= \sum_n \alpha_n z^{p_n}$ whose circle of convergence is the unit circle and for which the unit circle is not the natural boundary. You have identified two sets satisfying this condition.

Set 1: $\mathbb{N}$

Set 2: {$x \in \mathbb{N} | \nexists n \in \mathbb{N}[2^n=x]$}

As per the theorem, there exist sequences $\alpha_n$ for set 1 and $\beta_n$ for set 2 such that the corresponding power series have radius of convergence of 1 and for which the unit circle is not the natural boundary.

The theorem does not guarantee that you can take the sequence $\alpha_n$ that worked for set 1 and strip away the elements for which $n$ is a power of 2 to make a new power series that does not have the unit circle as the natural boundary. It only guarantees the existence of an unrelated sequence $\beta_n$ such that the power series formed with $\beta_n$ gives you this property.